# WPF Custom Control library : trying to bind to templatedparent property from a keyed resource, ancestor way fails

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

How can I make this custom control library binding work? The code is heavily simplified for the sake of brevity, the Listview chooses its current View among several Views thank to a Datatrigger in its style, I'm only showing one for the sake of brevity. The failing binding is the GridViewColumn.Width one

Themes/Generic.Xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1">

<DataTemplate x:Key ="myDataTemplate">
        <!--This visibility binding works-->
        <CheckBox Width="16" Height="16" x:Name="ItemCheckbox" 
            Visibility="{Binding CheckBoxVisibility, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                   AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomControl1}}}" />
</DataTemplate>

<GridView x:Name="myView" x:Key="myView" x:Shared="False">
    <!--this width binding fails : Cannot find source for binding-->
    <GridViewColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Header="Name" 
                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}" 
                    Width="{Binding NameColumnWidth, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                          AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomControl1}}}" />
</GridView>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                        Path=ItemsSource}" >

                        <ListView.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                     Path=ViewDetails}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="View" 
                            Value="{StaticResource myView}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                     Path=ViewDetails}" Value="False ">
                                        <Setter Property="View" 
                             Value="{StaticResource myView2}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.Style>
                </ListView>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

CustomControl1.cs

```
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    //these properties should be DependencyProperties, simplified here for the sake of brevity
    ObservableCollection<Item> items;
    public object ItemsSource { get => items; }

    //this is the property I fail to bind to
    public double NameColumnWidth { get => this.Width; }

    //this one works
    public Visibility CheckBoxVisibility { get => Visibility.Visible; }

    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
I actually ended up changing my approach and instead of binding the column width to a Property in the templated parent I made it auto resizing to its content by subclassing GridView. This is an overall better solution. If anyone finds a solution to this binding puzzle I'll still be happy to test and accept it.

```
public class AutoAdjustingGridView: GridView
{

    protected override void PrepareItem(ListViewItem item)
    {
        base.PrepareItem(item);
        foreach(var column in Columns)
        {
            if (double.IsNaN(column.Width))
                column.Width = column.ActualWidth;

            column.Width = double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set DataContext to this in non static constructor of control ex. DataContext = this;

Comment: The problem seems to be related to setting `ListView.View` through a `Style` - if you set it directly with `StaticResource` extension the bindings work as expected. Don't know how to solve this pickle yet though. It's possible you'll have to change your approach entirely (e.g. subclass `GridView` and set up the columns in the constructor).

Comment: @ macieqqq : Adding a non-static constructor makes the control fail to initialize with a XamlParseException

Comment: @Grx70 The ListView style is there to select the appropriate view. I edited the original post to show this. Maybe I should resort to have several ListViews, each with its own view, and hide those I dont want to see.